# Windows Architecture (for mobile development) W10 vs. W8.1 and WinRT vs. UWP vs. Others

Tags: winapi, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, uwp, windows-10-mobile

I'm a little confused and do not know whether I understand the issues properly, so be sure to I turn to you for help.
I have Windows 10 Pro X68, for development using VS 2015 and SDK 10. And I write the bachelor work that deals with the development of applications for Windows Phone 8.1 and now also for Windows Mobile 10 (UWP).

1. I'm wondering, as illustrated below, if Windows 10 include "**Desktop
   Apps**" section as in architecture W8.1 (is Desktop App section from W8.1 image available in W10)?
2. I read that the **UWP** is an improved version of **WinRT** for all platforms, and is not used name
   WinRT(in W10), but the name **UWP**?
3. **WinRT** replaced **Win32** application development for mobile platform
   (Metro UI - Apps Store), but for Win32 can develop in W10 and W8.1?

Sorry for my English.
THX a lot.

[image: WinRT Revealed]
*(WinRT Revealed, 2012, Michael Mayberry, 978-1-4302-4584-1)*
[image: Real World Windows 10 Development]
*(Real World Windows 10 Development, 2015,Edard Moemeka and Elizabeth Moemeka, 978-1-4842-1450-3)*

Comment: Desktop apps still exist on Win 10. I don't really understand the other questions.

Comment: The first sheet is still valid I think, the blue columns are also available in Win10.

Comment: Other questions to ask, what are the relationships between and support WinRT (Windows8.1 / Windows Phone 8.1), Win32 and UWP (Windows 10) between the platform from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10.

Whether the WinRT from Windows 8.1 is Called in Windows 10 UWP, UWP is the final product, the gradual development of WinRT. In Win10 is the UWP element of WinRT?

UWP is part of the WinRT? With that UWP is an improved and expanded version of the WinRT (which is so called Windows 8 / 8.1 WinRT, but in Windows 10, this architecture has called UWP). I read this from the Books about development Win10 & 8.

Comment: UWP is new platform for Windows 10, it's actively developed and it is getting new features and capabilities with every major version of W10 (November update, Anniversary update, upcoming Creators update...). It was developed from the WinRT but UWP is fully universal, so one code could run on every W10 device.

Comment: The Windows Runtime (WinRT) was introduced in Windows 8, as a COM-based wrapper around the Windows API (Win32). In that respect, it's similar to .NET, but fully implemented in native, unmanaged code. The Universal Windows Platform is built on top of WinRT, as a consolidated development platform for all Windows 10 devices (Mobile, HoloLens, PC, ...). You can create Win32 desktop applications for Windows 10 (Desktop and Server).